# How to click buttons in Gmail using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail

I'm trying to click on "insert link" button in Gmail compose dialog using jquery in chrome console, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
$('div[command="+link"]').click();
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YadPX.png)

Comment: Google generally generates cryptic ids and class names on each page load (this means that a definitive selector might not be possible). What is your use case for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this...

```
document.querySelector("div[command='+link']")
        .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousedown"));
```

Comment: He is trying to do this with jQuery. It's not the invocation that's wrong, it's his selector.

Comment: @MarioTacke he would't be able to use jQuery in this context without injecting it (Gmail doesn't use jQuery). And the **invocation** was wrong, not the selector. There's not a handler for a `click` event bound to this button, the behavior of opening that modal window is triggered on the `mousedown` event (I tried to remove the specific handler I'm talking about, and voilà, no more modals). Hence, to achieve this programatically, he needs to trigger the `mousedown` event specifically.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to clarify this! I'll see myself out.

Comment: @AlcidesQueirozAguiar BTW is there any way to click on the close compose window? http://i.imgur.com/WqOXhjr.png I've tried to change selector to class ".Ha" but nothing happens. Classes are static and do not changed after the refresh. Thanks for your help.